# Android unzip not a directory issue

Tags: java, android

I am trying to unzip a zip file which is stored in the raw folder. Code is as follows

```
try
{
    File myDir = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath());
    File newFile = new File(myDir + "/imageFolder");

if(!newFile.exists())
                    {
                        newFile.mkdir();
                    }

    ZipInputStream zipIs = new ZipInputStream(con
            .getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.images));
    ZipEntry ze = null;

    while ((ze = zipIs.getNextEntry()) != null)
    {

        Log.v("Name", ze.getName());
        Log.v("Size", "" + ze.getSize());

        if(ze.getSize() >0)
        {
            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(newFile
                    + "/" + ze.getName());                      

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length = 0;

            while ((length = zipIs.read(buffer)) > 0)
            {
                fout.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            zipIs.closeEntry();
            fout.close();
        }   
        }

    zipIs.close();

} catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But I keep getting this error

> 01-18 11:24:28.301: W/System.err(2285): java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /data/data/com.example.ziptests/files/imageFolder/TestImages/background.png
>   (Not a directory)

I have absolutely no idea why it is causing this, it finds the files, but when it comes to writing them out, it brings up that error. Originally I found a problem that was caused by having the zip file zipped up on the mac, so I zipped up the file on my windows machine instead, that got rid of one problem (when you zip on a mac, it adds these extra folders and files such s store.ds which causes an error when trying to unzip), but this not a directory error keeps coming up.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: the zip file is compressed using winzip software?

Comment: Yeah I zipped it on Windows rather than on the mac as zipping on the mac causes issues as it adds in extra folders which is annoying

Answer (score 0):

Please try below link code for unzip zip file.

**Code for Extract Zip File**

[Unzip Zip File](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Unzipping_Files_with_Android_%28Programmatically%29)

The Problem is I am Uploading zip File which is not made using winrar software, so it is not proper extracted and give me error.

It will solve your problem.

Comment: Okay I used the decompress code, and updated it to take an inputstream rather than a string for its zip location. However it is taking over a  minute to extract all the images, and it eventually crashes while trying to unzip them all, there are only 42 small images. Any reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't write files to the `raw` folder. It is a read only dir intended to contain resource files included in your apk.

---

UPDATE
That file would be better in the `assets` directory. You can access it through the [`AssetManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html). If not, leave it in the `res/raw` dir, but access it through [`Resources.openRawResource`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResource%28int%29). Either way they are Read-Only.

Comment: I am not writing to the raw folder, I am only reading from the raw folder

Comment: You said "when it comes to writing them out...". Anyway, move your zip file from res to `assets` folder, and get the file as I'm about to post in the answer.

Comment: But if you look at my code, I am not trying to write out to the raw folder, only read from it, then write out to the internal storage on the phone